# Flutter - Pass data from a Future variable(sqlite) to a widget

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, widget

I am very new to Flutter and Dart but I am trying to get data from a sqlite method and pass it as an argument to a new widget.
I've tried using FutureBuilder and it didn't help.

I am calling the method to load the data, wait for the data in .then() and inside then I set the state of a class variable to later be assigned to widget but the variable _records is always null even after setState.

```
Below is my code

int initScreen;

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  initScreen = await prefs.getInt("initScreen");


  await prefs.setInt("initScreen", 1);

  runApp(MyApp());
}


class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState  extends State{

  List<Quarter> _records;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _getRecords();

    super.initState();


  }
  _getRecords() async {
    await QuarterData().getQuarters().then((list){
      setState((){
        this. _records = list;
      });
    });
    return list;


  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'UI',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home:  initScreen == 0 || initScreen == null
                  ? SpashScreen(this._records)
                  : QuartersHome(this._records)

               );

  }
}
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this._records` is not initialised and will be null until your query is not done.

You need to check if it's not null before returning your widgets with it (like you do with `initScreen`)

If after the `setState()`method your variable is still null, maybe it's your query which return null.

Comment: Thank you very much. I added the check and everything working perfect now!